# ASP.NET Webdeploy failing; AddScheduledJob does not exist in project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-webjobs

I have an ASP.NET project with two WebJobs, one of the WebJobs publishes fine but the second fails to publish and I get the following error message:

The target "AddScheduledJob" does not exist in the project.

Both WebJobs where set up in the "Run on Demand" mode.

I am struggling to find any explanation for this error and cannot see what is different between my two WebJobs.  Anyone come across this?

**Edited**

I eventually found the problem thanks to David Ebbo pointing me in the right direction. I found that I had ended up with two import lines in the .csproj file of one of my WebJobs projects:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.2\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

After deleting the first of these everything worked fine.  I don't know how this happened but can only assume that something went wrong when I updated the NuGet package.

Comment: Can you make sure you have the latest version of the WebJobs publishing NuGet package? Also, what version of VS are you using?

Comment: I have the latest version of WebJobs.Publish v1.1.0 and I am using VS 2017.  BTW, the WebJob does seem to publish and run, but I am still getting this error when I attempt to deploy.

Comment: VS publishing expert says it might be related to missing the msbuild import. See if you have [this](https://github.com/vijayrkn/ASPNetPublishSamples/blob/bff9f78d796668dc07d5e28a8b93531caade839c/WebAppWithWebJob/WebAppWithWebJob.csproj#L245). Also compare your working vs non working cases for differences.

Comment: Ideally, if you can share what both WebJobs csproj look like, that would allow identifying differences.

Comment: @DavidEbbo I have checked that both csproj files contain the Import Project line for WebJobs.Publish, although they are different versions.

Comment: Can you simplify the repro to the point that you can share it, per [this page](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue)? Otherwise, it's a guessing game :)

Comment: I had the same problem and your comments helped me. Make sure that the version in <import> element is the same one than the one installed by NuGet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had a similar problem when I had existing WebJob SDK projects under an ASP.NET site, and I added a new one.  The new one was using a newer version of the Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish package.

I used the "Add Existing Project as Azure WebJob" flow to add it, and then I noticed **in the ASP.NET project** that there were now two Imports:

```
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.10\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.10\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

I simply **removed the Import with the older version** and that took care of it.

Answer (score 3):

In your WebJob project delete the webjob-publish-settings.json file also delete the webjobs-list.json from your WebAPI project.

Now,  In WebAPI Project Right Click > Add > Existing Project As Azure Web Job, This will recreate the webjob-publish-settings.json and webjobs-list.json files and should fix the issue.