# "The target 'AddScheduledJob' does not exist in the project" when publishing to Azure from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-webjobs

My solution consists of a main web app, with several azure web jobs attached to it. When I go to publish the main web app, I receive this error:

```
[project_path]\[project_name].csproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "AddScheduledJob" does not exist in the project.
```

I'm not sure where `AddScheduledJob` is coming from. It is **not** the name of any project in the solution.

I think I have tracked down the file that is "attempting" to reference this phantom project:

```
[solution_path]\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets
```

This file contains this snippet of text:

```
 <Target Name="AddScheduledJob"
      DependsOnTargets="$(AddScheduledJobDependsOn)"
      AfterTargets="MSDeployPublish"
      Condition="'$(FilePreview)' == 'false' and ('$(WebJobPublishFromWAP)' == 'true' or '$(_DestinationType)' == 'AzureWebSite')">

<CreateScheduledWebJob JobConfig="@(JobConfig)"  
                       WebSiteName="$(WebSiteName)" 
                       WebSiteUrl="$(WebSiteUrl)"
                       ManagementUri="$(WebJobManagementUri)"
                       ManagementCertificatePath="$(ManagementCertificatePath)"
                       ManagementCertificatePassword="$(ManagementCertificatePassword)"
                       ManagementCertificate="$(ManagementCertificate)"
                       ManagementToken="$(ManagementToken)"
                       PublishSettingsPath="$(PublishSettingsPath)"
                       SubscriptionId="$(SubscriptionId)"
                       Condition="'%(RunMode)' == 'Scheduled'"/>
```

I have no idea where this is coming from, or why it is causing a problem. I am tempted to just remove that snippet, but at the top of the file, I read this snippet:

```
WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file, this file is added to your project automatically...
```

Can I safely remove this snippet from the "webjobs.console.targets" file? Or, is there something else that might be going on?

**UPDATE**

I discovered that even with this error, my web app is successfully getting published. Here is a more in-depth view of the logs at the end of the publish process:

```
Adding ACLs for path (ringclone-test/App_Data)
Publish Succeeded.
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets (25,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\TicketProcessor\TicketProcessor.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets (25,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\TicketDistributor\TicketDistributor.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets (25,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\ArchiveIndexer\ArchiveIndexer.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.console.targets (24,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\Starter\Starter.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.console.targets (24,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\NrtTrigger\NrtTrigger.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets (25,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\DownloadProcessor\DownloadProcessor.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.1.0\tools\webjobs.console.targets (24,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\DatabaseReIndexer\DatabaseReIndexer.csproj]
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(110,5): Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: Webjob configuration is missing metadata for StartTime
C:\APD\RingClone\DailyMaintenance\DailyMaintenance.csproj(0,0): Error MSB4057: The target "AddScheduledJob" does not exist in the project.
C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(25,3): Warning MSB4011: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" cannot be imported again. It was already imported at "C:\APD\RingClone\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.12\tools\webjobs.console.targets (25,3)". This is most likely a build authoring error. This subsequent import will be ignored. [C:\APD\RingClone\ScheduledTrigger\ScheduledTrigger.csproj]
```

As you can see, it says "publish succeeded", then complains about the "StartTime" for one of the jobs. And then complains about the "AddScheduledJob". I'm not concerned about the "StartTime" issue. I can get that fixed. But the error about the project called "AddScheduledJob" is baffling. Even though the publish seems to happen, I don't want this error cluttering up the log. What is causing this error?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to add the `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` package from Nuget. Even though VS has the publish to Web Job action, it doesn’t automatically add that package to your project.  You could refer to this [blog](http://www.rhizohm.net/resolving-the-msdeploypublish-error-when-publishing-azure-web-jobs-from-visual-studio-2015/).

Once you add it, you’re still screwed. VS doesn’t automatically modify your `.csproj` file to use this package. 
To do so, you need manually hack your `.csproj` file. Easiest way is to unload it in VS and add the following line right after the CSharp targets – I’ve included it below for context:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.11\tools\webjobs.targets" 
Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.11\tools\webjobs.targets')" />
```

Here is a similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46848211/asp-net-webdeploy-failing-addscheduledjob-does-not-exist-in-project) with you. When he add a new WebJob under asp.net site, retain the newer version of `Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish` package.

Answer (score 0):

That's an ancient NuGet package. In older versions, Visual Studio would allow you to configure the schedule of a webjob if you configured it to run on a schedule instead of continuously. You can remove that target and configure the schedule using the following guidance: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs#CreateScheduledCRON . If you're using an older version of Visual Studio, please upgrade so that you have the latest WebJob project template.